# How to Show Bitmap without blur from EditText

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-edittext

I am creating one application in that i need to capture image or text from EditText in format of `bitmap`. It's done perfectly. But When there is only one smiley inside `EditText` at that image became blur.I want that image without blur. Here is my code for capturing smiley from `EditText`.

```html
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
edtInput.setCursorVisible(false);
edtInput.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
edtInput.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(edtInput.getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(edtInput.getMeasuredHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
edtInput.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(edtInput.getDrawingCache(),0,0,edtInput.getMeasuredWidth(), edtInput.getMeasuredHeight());
Uri screenshotUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bmp);
sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
edtInput.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
edtInput.setCursorVisible(true);
```

This code fetch bitmap from EditText and scale then to there size but when there is only one smiley then it became blur otherwise it works fine. Please Help me.. Thanks in advance..